# Using Slice Pipe with variable parameters in *ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Using the Angular2 pipe `slice` I can do something like this to only show the first five elements of my `items`.

```
<ion-item *ngFor='let item of items | slice:0:5">
```

How can I use variables instead of hardcoding 0 and 5? I want to do something like this and define `start` and `end` in my *.ts file.

```
<ion-item *ngFor='let item of items | slice:"start":"end"'>
```

Comment: use it without double quotes `<ion-item *ngFor='let item of items | slice:start:end'>`

Comment: Thank you. I accidently put an "start : 0" and "end : 5" in my *.ts file instead of "start = 0" and "end = 5". Then it didn't work obviously...When I corrected this it worked just fine without the quotes - as you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just remove `"`(double quotes) from the `start` and `end` variable

```
<ion-item *ngFor='let item of items | slice:start:end'>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the slice: 0:5 does not work.
here is my solution

```
 <div class="symbol-group symbol-hover" 
                            *ngFor='let memebr of group?.Members.slice(0,5); let j=index,let y=last'>
            </div>
```