# Angular condition slicepipe in a ngfor

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to know how can I use an conditional slicepipe in an ngFor to control the data displayed ?

For example to choose the number of videos displayed on a list/grid for example like these commons dropdowns :

[image: imageref1]

What I'm trying to do now is:

```
<app-example
      class="items-list-item"
      *ngFor="let item of datas.video | slice:0:1"
      [itemvideo]='item'>
</app-example>
```

But how I can do this dynamically when I change the value on the select dropdown ?

Comment: Just set the item size to a variable and use it instead of 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Slice Pipe with variable parameters in \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944570/using-slice-pipe-with-variable-parameters-in-ngfor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to define the variable and assign those values

```
 start : number = 1;
 end : number = 5;
```

then change it according to the dropdown value

```
this.end = yourdropdownval;
```

and the ngFor will look like,

```
<app-example class="items-list-item" *ngFor="let item of datas.video  | slice:start:end'>
```

Comment: Thanks, I could resolve my problem with your answer